# R: Barplot with multiple categorical variables on the x axis (more than 2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape

I am struggling to create a barplot that contain multiple categorical variables, so my current data looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B"), Score1 = c(10,20,30,40), Type2 = c("C","C","D","D"), Score2 = c(20,40,60,80))
ID  Type1    Score1   Type2    Score2
1       A        10       C        20
2       B        20       C        40
3       A        30       D        60
4       B        40       D        80
```

and what I am looking for should look like this

[image]

Next I want to take this even further by adding more category to the graph, so the data frame is now

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B"), Score1 = c(10,20,30,40), Type2 = c("C","C","D","D"), Score2 = c("20","40","60","80"), Colour = c("Black","White","Black","White"))
ID  Type1    Score1   Type2    Score2    Colour
1       A        10       C        20     Black
2       B        20       C        40     White
3       A        30       D        60     Black
4       B        40       D        80     White
```

and for this one it should look like this

[image]

When there is only one type, I usually `reshape` the data and do this with the `ggplot` command. (and most of the answer I found online is pretty much just this one)
However, there is now more than just one type. I'm not really sure how should I go with this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: if the first one is `with(mtcars, barplot(table(vs, am), beside = TRUE))`, the second one is `with(mtcars, barplot(ftable(vs, am, gear), beside = TRUE))`

Comment: @rawr I'm so sorry I don't totally understand it... Should I somehow reshape my data first somehow since I not sure how I should specify x and y?

Comment: @rawr, though your solution seems interesting, when you compute `ftable()` you are computing only the number of elements not the means, right? I think that for this situation `ftable()` may not fit very well...

Comment: @LuísTelles what? I agree that not all situations can be processed the same way.. the point is to get the data in a matrix, _however one might accomplish this_, and make a simple barplot `barplot(matrix(rnorm(12), 4, dimnames = list(NULL, 1:3)), beside = TRUE)` see I didnt use ftable?

Comment: @rawr, I was referring to the fact that it is written in the plot titles 'Averages' and that we have groups of samples. In this sense, I think the OP wanted **the matrix to be of averages** instead of a frequency matrix or just the original values in a matrix.

Comment: @Maru your hand drawn graph does not match your data. There are no cases of `Type1 "A" `which are `"White"`

Comment: @RoryShaw My apologies I just made a really simplify version of my actual data and forgot to think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've attempted to create a `tidyverse` solution here:

For your first dataframe - `df`

```
library(tidyverse)

#tidy the dataframe
df_1 <- df %>% select(ID, Type1, Score1) %>% rename(Type = Type1, Score = Score1) %>% mutate(Type_number = as.factor(1), Score_number = as.factor(1))
df_2 <- df %>% select(ID, Type2, Score2) %>% rename(Type = Type2, Score = Score2) %>% mutate(Type_number = as.factor(2), Score_number = as.factor(2))
df_tidy <- bind_rows(df_1, df_2) %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor(.)), ID, Type, Type_number, Score_number)

#summarise the dataframe - create means of scores by Type
df_sum <- df_tidy %>% group_by(Type, Score_number) %>% summarise(Mean_score = mean(Score))

#create plot
ggplot(df_sum, aes(x = Type, y = Mean_score, fill = Score_number)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

For your second dataframe - `df2`

```
#tidy the dataframe
df_3 <- df2 %>% select(ID, Type1, Score1, Colour) %>% rename(Type = Type1, Score = Score1) %>% mutate(Type_number = as.factor(1), Score_number = as.factor(1))
df_4 <- df2 %>% select(ID, Type2, Score2, Colour) %>% rename(Type = Type2, Score = Score2) %>% mutate(Type_number = as.factor(2), Score_number = as.factor(2), Score = as.numeric(as.character(Score)))
df_tidy_2 <- bind_rows(df_3, df_4) %>% mutate_each(funs(as.factor(.)), ID, Type, Type_number, Score_number, Colour)

#summarise the dataframe - create means of scores by Type
df_sum_2 <- df_tidy_2 %>% group_by(Type, Score_number, Colour) %>% summarise(Mean_score = mean(Score))

#create plot
ggplot(df_sum_2, aes(x = Type, y = Mean_score, fill = Score_number)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Colour, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

My feeling though is that this is not really the solution you are looking for? Its not clear to me what the purpose of the analysis is - what is the question you are trying to answer. Anyway, hope this helps.

Comment: This works just fine! Thank you suggesting the ggplot solution
Sorry it took me a while to try to apply this to my actual data.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first request, please try:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B"), Score1 = c(10,20,30,40), Type2 = c("C","C","D","D"), Score2 = c(20,40,60,80))

ab_means <- tapply(df$Score1, df$Type1, mean)
cd_means <- tapply(df$Score2, df$Type2, mean)

par(xpd = TRUE)
bp <- barplot(c(ab_means, cd_means), main = 'Average', ylab = 'Score', font.lab = 2)
text(x = mean(bp[1:2,]), y = -10, labels = 'Score 1', font = 2)
text(x = mean(bp[3:4,]), y = -10, labels = 'Score 2', font = 2)

ns <- length(df$Score1[df$Type1 == 'A'])
ns1 <- length(df$Score1[df$Type1 == 'B'])
ns2 <- length(df$Score2[df$Type2 == 'C'])
ns3 <- length(df$Score2[df$Type2 == 'D'])

text(x = bp, y = c(ab_means, cd_means)+1.5, labels = sapply(as.character(c(ns, ns1, ns2, ns3)), function(x) paste('n =', x)))
```

[image]

Regarding the more complex request, please try:

```
# Make the dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B"), Score1 = c(10,20,30,40), Type2 = c("C","C","D","D"), Score2 = c("20","40","60","80"), Colour = c("Black","White","Black","White"))


# Define plot region
par(mfcol = c(1,2), # two columns, one row
    xpd = TRUE, # let things be plotted outside of the plotting region
    mar = c(5, 4, 6, 2)) # margins of the plotting region


# Compute the means
ab_black_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score1[df2$Colour == 'Black'])), df$Type1[df2$Colour == 'Black'], mean)
cd_black_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score2[df2$Colour == 'Black'])), df$Type2[df2$Colour == 'Black'], mean)

ab_white_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score1[df2$Colour == 'White'])), df$Type1[df2$Colour == 'White'], mean)
cd_white_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score2[df2$Colour == 'White'])), df$Type2[df2$Colour == 'White'], mean)

# Compute the maximum score value to set the scale
all <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df2[, c('Score1', 'Score2')]))
max_all <- ceiling(max(all, na.rm = TRUE))

# First barplot
bp1 <- barplot(c(ab_black_means, cd_black_means), ylab = 'Score', font.lab = 2, ylim = c(0, max_all))
text(x = mean(bp1[1:2,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 1', font = 2)
text(x = mean(bp1[3:4,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 2', font = 2)

# Compute the Ns to plot above each bar
ns <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'A' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns1 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'B' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns2 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'C' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns3 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'D' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))


text(x = bp1, y = c(ab_black_means, cd_black_means)+2, labels = sapply(as.character(c(ns, ns1, ns2, ns3)), function(x) paste('n =', x)))
axis(side = 1, at = bp1, labels = rep('', 4))

text(x = mean(bp1[1:4]), y = par('usr')[3]-16, labels = 'Black', font = 2, cex = 1.3)


# Second barplot
bp2 <- barplot(c(ab_white_means, cd_white_means), yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, max_all))
text(x = mean(bp2[1:2,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 1', font = 2)
text(x = mean(bp2[3:4,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 2', font = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = bp2, labels = rep('', 4))

# Compute the Ns to plot above each bar
ns4 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'A' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns5 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'B' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns6 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'C' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns7 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'D' & df2$Colour == 'White']))

text(x = bp1, y = c(ab_white_means, cd_white_means)+2, labels = sapply(as.character(c(ns4, ns5, ns6, ns7)), function(x) paste('n =', x)))

text(x = mean(bp2[1:4]), y = par('usr')[3]-16, labels = 'White', font = 2, cex = 1.3)


# Final title
title(main = 'Average Score', outer = TRUE, line = -3)
```

[image]

In this last plot note that some bars won't appear. That's because some means could not be computed (note that we can't have a `mean` for factor `B` and color `'Black'`).

If you really want the x axis to be continuous without any interruptions you may use `curve()`:

```
# Make the dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Type1 = c("A","B","A","B"), Score1 = c(10,20,30,40), Type2 = c("C","C","D","D"), Score2 = c("20","40","60","80"), Colour = c("Black","White","Black","White"))


# Define plot region
par(mfcol = c(1,2), # two columns, one row
    xpd = TRUE, # let things be plotted outside of the plotting region
    mar = c(5, 4, 6, 2)) # margins of the plotting region


# Compute the means
ab_black_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score1[df2$Colour == 'Black'])), df$Type1[df2$Colour == 'Black'], mean)
cd_black_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score2[df2$Colour == 'Black'])), df$Type2[df2$Colour == 'Black'], mean)

ab_white_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score1[df2$Colour == 'White'])), df$Type1[df2$Colour == 'White'], mean)
cd_white_means <- tapply(as.numeric(as.character(df2$Score2[df2$Colour == 'White'])), df$Type2[df2$Colour == 'White'], mean)

# Compute the maximum score value to set the scale
all <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df2[, c('Score1', 'Score2')]))
max_all <- ceiling(max(all, na.rm = TRUE))

# First barplot
bp1 <- barplot(c(ab_black_means, cd_black_means), ylab = 'Score', font.lab = 2, ylim = c(0, max_all))
text(x = mean(bp1[1:2,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 1', font = 2)
text(x = mean(bp1[3:4,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 2', font = 2)

# Compute the Ns to plot above each bar
ns <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'A' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns1 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'B' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns2 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'C' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))
ns3 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'D' & df2$Colour == 'Black']))


text(x = bp1, y = c(ab_black_means, cd_black_means)+2, labels = sapply(as.character(c(ns, ns1, ns2, ns3)), function(x) paste('n =', x)))
axis(side = 1, at = bp1, labels = rep('', 4))

text(x = mean(bp1[1:4]), y = par('usr')[3]-16, labels = 'Black', font = 2, cex = 1.3)

# First curve added
curve(expr = 0*x+0, from = 0, to = 6, add = TRUE, col = 'black')


# Second barplot
bp2 <- barplot(c(ab_white_means, cd_white_means), yaxt = 'n', ylim = c(0, max_all))
text(x = mean(bp2[1:2,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 1', font = 2)
text(x = mean(bp2[3:4,]), y = par('usr')[3]-11, labels = 'Score 2', font = 2)
axis(side = 1, at = bp2, labels = rep('', 4))

# Compute the Ns to plot above each bar
ns4 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'A' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns5 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type1 == 'B' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns6 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'C' & df2$Colour == 'White']))
ns7 <- c(length(df2$Score1[df2$Type2 == 'D' & df2$Colour == 'White']))

text(x = bp1, y = c(ab_white_means, cd_white_means)+2, labels = sapply(as.character(c(ns4, ns5, ns6, ns7)), function(x) paste('n =', x)))

text(x = mean(bp2[1:4]), y = par('usr')[3]-16, labels = 'White', font = 2, cex = 1.3)

# Second curve added
curve(expr = 0*x+0, from = -10, to = 5, add = TRUE, col = 'black')

# Final title
title(main = 'Average Score', outer = TRUE, line = -3)
```

[image]

Please let me know if it works for you and if I may assist you any further. Hope it helps!

Comment: This works just fine as well! Thanks for suggesting the boxplot method ^ ^